# Move to SD Card Option Greyed out even for Compatible Apps

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, art, motorola-moto-e

I am using a Motorola Moto E with Android Kitkat and I am unable to move applications to my SD Card even for Apps that support moving to SD Card.

I am using ART Runtime (Developer) instead of Dalvik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using ART, you cannot move apps to the SD card. 
Media moves are fine. 
You can switch to Dalvik, move apps, and then switch back to ART. 
ART is a developer option for Android Kitkat.